# How to use serverspec docker resource on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: rspec, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife, serverspec

I have following structure -

Bastion(EC2 instance with public DNS) -> Private EC2 instance on which docker container is running.

Now, I can see docker container running by ssh to Bastion using `ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@ec2.us-west-amazon.com` followed by `ssh -i key.pem <private EC2 instance IP>` followed by `docker ps -a`

I have 15 different private EC2 instances with different docker containers. I want to ssh to each private EC2 instance and check properties of each docker container.

With serverspec I was trying something like this -

```
describe command('ssh -i QA.pem  ec2-user@us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com') do

    describe command('ssh -t -t 10.0.5.5 docker ps -a') do  
        its(:stdout) { should contain('web-server') }
    end

end
```

How can we achieve this using serverspec? Or serverspec is not good choice for this?

Comment: That's a better starting point, I'm far to be expert with serverspec, but I'm pretty sure the command won't be chained, more sequentially executed, and as the first one isn't ended, you won't get to the inner one. (But that's a guess, I may be wrong there and I let more knowledgeable people confirm or infirm this)

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you want to check (maybe if you could enumerate those, it would be easier to tell you if serverspec already has any of those features?). This sounds like a for loop with some docker commands, so I'm not sure you're going to get a lot out of an additional framework.

Given all that, it's trivial to write a loop to run some commands and test output in serverspec:

```
machines = %w(10.1.2.3 10.4.5.6 10.7.8.9)
machines.each do |ip|
  describe command("ssh #{ip} 'docker ps -a'") do
    its(:stdout) { should match /bin/ }
    its(:stderr) { should match /failed/ }
    its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
  end
end
```

I don't think the above example is going to buy you a lot over a for loop in bash with grep for results, but we'd really need to know more details to know if there's a benefit to having serverspec in the mix.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Here is the link for server spec docker support http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#docker_image. In your example you are doing 1 level of ssh in for loop where in my case there are 2 levels of ssh. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @rohitkadam19 Is it that hard to extend the answer ? i.e: `ssh #{bastion-ip} 'ssh #'{ip} \'docker ps -a\''` (I'm unsure escaping quotes and even quotes are necessary, but testing is left as an exercise)

Comment: @Tensibai It's not that hard to extend answer, I have tried same command manually what you mentioned. I was trying to find some best way using serverspec.

Comment: @rohitkadam19 In this case, I would open a new question linking there, showing what you actually tried and explaining why it does not fit or showing logs of where it fail. (that's how SO is meant to work, it's not a forum where you expand the question after each new anwser). (Edit: I feel a bit harsh, sorry, just trying to give you guidance and can't phrase it better :/)

Comment: @Tensibai Added serverspec snippet. Let me know if it's useful. Thanks for advice.